# Colour Name to RGB/Hex/HSL/HSV etc

Tags: colors, hex, rgb, hsv, hsl

I have come across this great [function/command](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/col2rgb.html). Colour to RGB, you can do this:

```
col2rgb("peachpuff")
//returns hex
```

It will return one hex value. I want to extend this using Perl, Python or PHP but I want to be able to pass in, for example, "yellow" and the function returns all types of yellows - their hex/rgb/?/etc value.

I already have a quick solution implemented, which involves mapping colour names to hex values but now I want to get more precise and use some formulas etc to determine what's what.

However, as usual, I don't have a clue on how to do this! So I appreciate any implementation advice on how to do this.

Thanks all

Comment: Do you have any examples of what sort of things you'd be passing in that could be calculated?

Comment: @Slokun - what do you mean? I will be passing in strings such as "yellow", "purple", "pink" etc - and hoping to return rgb or hex values of all those colours that fit into that string or group of colours.

Comment: If you're just using base colours, you couldn't use them for calculating, they'd have to be mapped, and used as your base. Something else would have to be calculated, such as `yellow-red` (which would make orange), `yellowy-orange`, `light blue`, etc. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Slokun - the mapped idea can be the base. So if "yellow" is passed in we can make use of "#FFFF00" or "255,255,0" as the base. From there, how can I generate the other rgb/hex family of yellows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical CSS color names originated in X11 and the intersection of the sets - along with their RGB values can be - [found at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names#Color_names_identical_between_X11_and_HTML.2FCSS).

A more easily parsed list can be found in [various rgb.txt](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/poplog/freebsd/new/rgb.txt) files scattered over the web, but these are likely the X11 set not the CSS set.

**added**: Given an RGB value you can compute nearby colors by [HSL conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB). Color palettes - sets of colors that go well together - are an art not a science, [Google 'em](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=color+palettes).

Comment: I am making use of a similar mapping already but it will return only one value. Not other similar colours or the yellow or green colour of families, if i passed in yellow or green.

Comment: If "yellow" is in-putted, return all other yellows that exist. This isn't a colour palette!! I had a look at that page already today - it didn't seem to find nearby colors, I'll have a look again, maybe the maths is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: `grep yellow rgb.txt` will do what I think you are asking, but it will give poor results because many color-names that you might call "yellow" don't have "yellow" in their names. You probably need to read up on what color means to better understand the question you are trying to ask. The idea "yellows" is more complicated than we normally think.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the ccs Color names.
W3c webstandard --> [CSS3/SVG Farben](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color)

Comment: I am making use of a similar mapping already but it will return only one value. Not other similar colours or the yellow or green colour of families, if i passed in yellow or green.